# regristry-editor resets changes to default after restart

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I have the convertible **Lenovo Yoga c940-14IIL** with Windows 10 Home Ver 2004 (about 2 years old).

Since about one Month, I have the problem, that my screen doesn't rotate anymore.
The rotation lock is greyed out as well.
I tried many solutions already an even when I fixed the rotation lock it doesn't rotate.

Then I found a solution with the registry editor, i.e. I turned the needed points on.
But when I restarted my Convertible, the changes reset (changed to default).

**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation**

How it is right now:

[image]

I need to turn all of the `1` to `0` and "save" the change.

Is there a way to do that?

I am pretty new to all this, so please excuse me if I forgot something important.

Best Regards and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your registry settings are fine. Zeroing then will *disable* AutoRotation.

Comment: The `"Enable"=dword:0000001` says you do enable the auto rotation. And of course the `SensorPresent` required be set to 1. You need to find out what actually reason that the screen doesn't rotate. Perhaps you have problem with the sensor, etc. See the following post: [https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/C940-screen-won-t-rotate-on-tablet-mode/m-p/4637218](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/C940-screen-won-t-rotate-on-tablet-mode/m-p/4637218?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

Some verification that you may do are listed below.
Ensure that your data is backed up before starting.

- This may be a hardware problem with your sensors.
  Microsoft Used to have a Sensors Troubleshooter that it dropped for some unknown
  reason. It can still be found in the
  [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20190910234934/https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/SensorDiagnosticTablet.diagcab)
  and might still work.
- Try
  [Lenovo Diagnostics for Windows 10](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-c940-14iil/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Diagnostic)
- Check if the problem exists when
  [booting in Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234),
  where only Windows software is enabled.
  If the problem disappears, then some third-party installed product is
  responsible for the problem.
  You may track this product using
  [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).
- Check for Windows corruption using the commands
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
  and DISM (explained in the link)
- If nothing is found, try to
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I tried the troubleshooting (failed because Windows location is truned off, turned it on in settings but still fails with same message).

Lenovo diagnostic said the acceleration sensor can not be reached.

I reseted my laptop to factory setting and it didn´t work, so i guess the rest won't work as well....

Comment: "the acceleration sensor can not be reached" : It's broken, unfortunately. In effect, there is no solution by software.

Comment: Is there a way to change it?

Comment: You mean replace the sensor? It might take a technician. I suggest contacting Lenovo Support and asking what are your options. If anything needs replacement, ask if it's possible to buy it.

Comment: Can you find the sensor in Device Manager??? Verify drivers before ass uming actual hardware failure.

Comment: I will contact lenovo support tomorrow. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @KeithMiller: I can only find **Intel (R) Sensor Collection** in Device Manager.

Comment: Does it report that it's functioning properly? If you highlight the Sensor Collection & switch the Device Manager view to `By Connection`, what is its "parent"? Any  "children"? Have you tried deleting it so it will be redetected?