# Acceleration Sensor not working (?)

Tags: lenovo-laptop, sensors

I have a **Lenovo c940-14IIL** and my screen doesn't rotate anymore on its own.
After trying everything out with the software, it seems like my acceleration sensor is not working/broken.

Is there a way:

1. Check if it really the sensor, why it is not working?
2. Get a new sensor and exchange it?

Thank you in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Does it show as okay in device manager?

Comment: Why have you abandoned your [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1650110/regristry-editor-resets-changes-to-default-after-restart)?

Comment: @spikey_richie: i don`t think so, under device manger I only have **Intel(R) Sensor Collection** and it seems fine. At least the driver says its fine.

Comment: @harrymc: Because the problem is not about the software anymore, so i thought i should open a new question. I'm sorry if that was wrong, i will mind it the next time.

Comment: Well, my answer there was that this is probably a problem with your sensor with a method for checking it.

Comment: I used Lenovo Diagnostic Tool and it gave me "it could not be read from the sensor".